# Asking for user input when using Invoke-Command

Tags: powershell

Recently ive been using a Powershell command in a Domain setting to Log off Remote users Who Do not log off at night After turning over with our night crew. I am using the command

```
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $name { quser }
```

After verifying the person is logged in.

```
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $name { logoff 2 }
```

(2 being the Session ID)
This works fine but it gets tiresome having to edit the .ps1 file everytime to change the name of the workstation. I'm trying to edit this command so it will ask for user input and then use the user input as the workstation that the Command is being run on, but whenever i use the following code it does not work.

```
    $name = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter the name of the computer' 
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName computer1 { quser }
```

This is only for quser right now after i get this sorted ill work on including Logoff 2. Sorry if im missing any information pretty new to Powershell.

Comment: you will need to run the interactive part BEFORE the `Invoke-Command` since that will be running in a different session [and almost always on an different computer]. the `quser.exe` command has an option to run against a remote system ... [*grin*]

Comment: Ah thank you that helps a bit appreciate it

Comment: you are very welcome! glad to help a tad ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

Since the remote desktop command-line tools can work remotely, there's no need to invoke a remote session with PowerShell. Try the following script that will *log off all users* on a remote machine.

```
param([string]$ComputerName)

# Cleanup the quser.exe output a little and turn it into an object
# Modified from: https://ss64.com/nt/query-user.html

$sessions = (quser /server:$ComputerName) -replace '\s{2,}', ',' -replace '>','' | ConvertFrom-Csv

foreach ($session in $sessions)
{
    Write-Output "Logging off user $($session.USERNAME) with session ID $($session.ID) on $ComputerName..."
    (logoff $session.ID /server:$ComputerName /V)
}
```

Example usage if script is saved as LogOffUsers.ps1 and run from a PowerShell prompt.

```
.\LogOffUsers.ps1 -ComputerName SFWEB01
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch i appreciate it. If i wanted to add user input how would i go about this? i dont really need to anymore but im just curious if its possible.

Comment: Ive tried running the script and it throws up an error for me saying Unexpexted token -Computer in expression or statement.

Comment: I had a typo in the usage example. The switch is ComputerName, not Computer.

Comment: Just add another param, like $Username, and then inside the foreach loop, only execute the code if $session.USERNAME -eq $Username